# Trying to call view from gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm just beginning working with Rails. 
Ive developed a ruby gem including views with some dynamic variables and i would like to call specific view from my rails project.
Do you have any approach to do that please?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the following will help with how to 'render' a view within the rails framework!

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Also, with regard to getting a hold of the views in the gem, it looks like if you have the views stored with 'app/views/' at the base of the gem, rails should pick that up so that subsequently when you render the view it would be as if you simply had the file within the views directory of the app!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Got it. Do you by any chance know what error is being thrown when you try to call the view?

Comment: No that's the issue. I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: Have you tried to call the method in the gem that generates the view? If so, did you receive an error message?

Comment: No, not yet. Can you please tell me how can i do it ?

Comment: Also, so basically you just pass 'the view' or whatever sort of representative you have for the view to the 'render' method to generate a response. Does that help?

Comment: Yes thats really help. I just called view using  render from my project and it worked. Thank you so much Drew ;).