# Creating Views In Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I do:

```
bundler new "gem_name"
```

This creates the basic structure for the gem.

```
cd "gem_name"
```

Now I am in my directory, TLD is by the of "gem_name"

Beneath that I create the app/views/hello_world.html.erb view I would like to load into other projects if they require my gem via

```
gem "gem_name"
```

I fill out the

```
"gem_name".gemspec
```

With the required information, and I do

```
rake install

gem list
```

confirms that "my_gem" is there.

So I create a new app, and I go into the gemfile of the new app, and enter "my_gem" in the gem file. I bundle install there. I don't see the view files I added in the gem (but the dependencies of my gem were loaded into my new app).  How do I load these views from a gem?

Ideally it would load right into the app views directory ( I can namespace later, just testing atm,..) without the need for a generator.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With regard to getting a hold of the views in the gem, it looks like if you have the views stored with '`app/views/`' at the base of the gem, rails should pick that up so that subsequently when you render the view it would be as if you simply had the file within the views directory of the app!

Hope this helps!

[Trying to call view from gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167844/trying-to-call-view-from-gem/26168793#26168793)

Comment: So the views are accessible, just not displayed within my app directory?  What If I want them to be seen in my new app, do I need a generator to install the views?

Comment: Correct, I do believe as long as they are stored in the proper directory. And I do believe I would just copy them over if you're wanting to have the views 'exposed', or seen within your new app should I say

Comment: So if I want to see the views packaged in a gem, I would have to go to the gem source and copy the files from there..?There's no way to just expose them with bundle install?

Comment: I guess that would be one way to go about it. I imagine whatever other technique you would use would just copy over the files or create some sort of link? Or is there a particular reason why you would want them viewable there -- you should be able to call them within the app as long as you include the gem!

Comment: Yeah... it's essentially a scaffold. I'd like the view files to be available to change...  Like devise views,  you have to run rails g devise:views.  I guess I'd like to do the same thing -- if there's no way to insert them by default

Comment: Ahh gotcha. I guess you could maybe just set up something similar within the gem and have that copy the files over if you're wanting to do it programatically, however my guess is that just copying and pasting the files manually would be quicker if you're just wanting to abstract the views from the gem?

Comment: Also, I guess if you're wanting to have a gem that is distributable and one which people can just generate whatever scaffolding they'd like, adding some methods within the gem would be the way to go!